# Pentaho - Spoon - Kettle delete if exist rows (obtained in a previous step) in a target table

Tags: sql, transformation, sql-delete, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I'm working in a transformation where I'm obtaining some data in stream, the problem is that I want to check if each element obtained exist in a table B (target), if those elements exist I want to delete each one of them, but the problem is that I don't know if exist something like a for each in kettle. Can anybody help me with this? Which step should I use?
I'm new in this world of kettles
I'll attach a screenshot bellow.

Thanks

[3 rows that I want to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyKsQ.png)

Comment: Please put your SQL in with formatted code (ctrl+k) sections with definitions of tables to have quick and willing helper(s)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an outer join with the rows of table B and then a filter to get only the rows that find results in that outer join. After that filter you can delete the rows.